# Find all duplicates except the first one, then get values from a different column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, duplicate

```
A     B                    

X1    16      
X2    17    
X2    18
X2    19 
X3    21
```

I have two columns as above.

If there are duplicates in Column `A` (here the duplicate value is "X2"), then I need to insert in another sheet:

1. value "18" - i.e. second value of duplicates
2. value "19" - i.e. subsequent value(s)

How can I find duplicates in column `A`, and then for all duplicates except the first one from each group, get the values from a different column?

I have tried with many IF, FIND formulas, but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your values are in cells `A2:B6`. You can accomplish this by performing the following steps:

1. Paste [the following formula](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/756657-highlight-all-duplicates-except-first-instance.html) into cell `C2` (and also provide a column header, if desired). This formula will return `TRUE` for all duplicates **that are not the first instance**, and it will return `FALSE` otherwise: `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2, A2)>1`

   [image: screenshot1]

2. Formula-copy cell `C2` down through cell `C6`

   [image: screenshot2]

3. Select cells `A1:C6`, click the "Data" ribbon, then click the "Filter" icon

   [image: screenshot3]

4. Click the filter dropdown that now exists in cell `C1`, and de-select the `FALSE` checkbox

   [image: screenshot4]

5. Select the values in column `B` that are still visible, and copy/paste to the new sheet

   [image: screenshot5]